# Divergence of a Swirl

Tags: divergence-theorem

What would the divergence of a swirl vector be of this image from google below?

[image]

I understand that divergence is the amount of fluid flow in and out of a point. As such, I think the divergence at any point is positive since the vector field lines point away from the point. This confuses me, however, because I normally think of the point of interest as a source or a sink. For example, this image:

[image]

Comment: If you put a particle in this fluid flow, would its path spiral out, spiral in, or make a circle?

Comment: If the flow is purely angular (no radial component), then the divergence is of course $0$.

Comment: From this picture I would say it is a bit ambiguous whether the divergence is positive or zero.